# why I am getting this error: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key Id in the item?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dynamodb-queries

when I am trying to post the data I am getting this error; One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key nineId in the item

This is the code.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region:'us-east-2'
})
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const dynamodbTableName = 'nine-project';

router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{
    const params = {
        TableName: dynamodbTableName,
        Item: req.body
      }
      await dynamodb.put(params).promise().then(() => {
        const body = {
          Operation: 'SAVE',
          Message: 'SUCCESS',
          Item: req.body
        }
        res.json(body);
      }, error => {
        console.error('Could not decode request: JSON parsing failed', error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
      })
    
})
```

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Sounds like your table requires a key `nineId` but the request does not contain such a key. Have you tried validating or even debugging the value in `req.body`?

Comment: check your `body`, pretty sure the pk for dynamodb is different or missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the primary key for the table. in this case you missed it that's why you are getting that error

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region:'us-east-2'
})
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const dynamodbTableName = 'nine-project';

router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{
const body = req.body;
body.nineId = "4a36251d-8668-4335-b746-527ff21a9ece";
// generate uuid for the object
    const params = {
        TableName: dynamodbTableName,
        Item: body
      }
      await dynamodb.put(params).promise().then(() => {
        const body = {
          Operation: 'SAVE',
          Message: 'SUCCESS',
          Item: req.body
        }
        res.json(body);
      }, error => {
        console.error('Could not decode request: JSON parsing failed', error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
      })
    
})
```